# Issues with changing the color of a header using a <select>-element

Tags: javascript

I am currently trying to change the color of a -element using JavaScript, with the help of the DOM-event "onchange".

```js
function changeColor() {
    var myHeader = document.getElementById("header");
    var mySelect = document.getElementById("select");

    header.style.color = mySelect.value;
}
```

```html
<h4 id="header">This is my header!</h4>

<form>

<select id="select" name="select" onchange="changeColor()">
    <option value="black">Black</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>

</form>
```

I think the problem is on the last line of code inside of the function. Please help a friend out!

Comment: Where do you define the `header` variable that you're trying to set?

Comment: copied and pasted your code to codepen, and I don't see any problem. The color of the header field was getting changed.

Comment: Change to `myHeader.style.color`. Voting to close due typo.

Comment: Shouldn't 'header.style.color' be 'myHeader.style.color'

Comment: So I just learned something new from this question. Apparently `id` will be accessible as a global-like variable. So the OP when he does `header.style.color = mySelect.value;` actually targets the node with `id="header"`. I get the idea that this is not best practice though. More reading here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3434388/1309377

Answer (score 1):

Although your code is working

```js
function changeColor() {
    var myHeader = document.getElementById("header");
    var mySelect = document.getElementById("select");
    header.style.color = mySelect.value;
}
```

```html
<h4 id="header">This is my header!</h4>
<form>

<select id="select" name="select" onchange="changeColor()">
    <option value="black">Black</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>

</form>
```

But you should use proper code as below, use `myHeader` instead `header`

```js
function changeColor() {
    var myHeader = document.getElementById("header");
    var mySelect = document.getElementById("select");
    myHeader.style.color = mySelect.value;
}
```

```html
<h4 id="header">This is my header!</h4>
<form>

<select id="select" name="select" onchange="changeColor()">
    <option value="black">Black</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>

</form>
```

Comment: I would remove the first code snippet and only show the correct one. People might just copy the first example they see in an answer without reading the context.

Comment: Ok, my code seems to be fully functional, although for some reason it doesn't work in Jsfiddle, which made me confused. It works in Codepen and in a regular text editor. Thank you for your answers.